# Pymc: Passing value to stochastic decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, pymc

I am trying to pass a value to the stochastic decorator using `value`.

```
@pymc.stochastic(value=(1.0, 1.0), dtype=np.float64)
def beta_priors(value):
    alpha, beta = value
    if alpha <= 0 or beta <= 0:
        return -np.inf
    else:
        return np.log(np.power((alpha + beta), -2.5))
```

Which I'm calling using `beta_priors(value=calc_tuple)[0]`

I get the error:

`TypeError: StochasticMeta object got multiple values for keyword argument 'value'`

How can I override the decorator's value keyword?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is way to override, but the documentations says that you cannot do that:

> The decorator stochastic can take any of the arguments
>   `Stochastic.__init__` takes except `parents`, `logp`, `random`, `doc` and `value`.

https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelbuilding.html?highlight=decorator#creation-of-stochastic-variables